# Android - How to keep default zoom/pan features with custom x-axis labels using AChartEngine

Tags: android, graph, label, achartengine

How do I apply custom x-axis labels to my AChartEngine BarGraph while keeping the same zoom/pan functionality as when default labels are used? The problem is that I have 100+ data points so I only want to draw 5 or 6 labels on the screen at a time.

The default functionality originally draws 3 labels (0, 50, and 100 in my case) and when zooming in, 4/5 labels are drawn. When panning left or right, the labels move along with the corresponding bars:

[image]
[image]

I have attempted two approaches however neither of them give me the same zoom and pan functionality as the default labels.

1) Generate 5 evenly spaced labels when the graph is first created.

- The problem with this is that it only creates 5 labels so when you zoom in too far, no labels are shown.

  ```
  //For 100 data points, add five labels every 20 datapoints
  mRenderer.addXTextLabel(0, "label 1");
  mRenderer.addXTextLabel(20, "label 2");
  mRenderer.addXTextLabel(40, "label 3");
  mRenderer.addXTextLabel(60, "label 4");
  mRenderer.addXTextLabel(80, "label 5");
  mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
  ```

2) Implement the ZoomListener and PanListener interfaces on my GraphicalView.

- This solution almost works, however the labels are always in fixed locations and are just "updated" with a new value when the graph is panned left or right. I need them to move with their corresponding bars.

  ```
  graphicalView.addZoomListener( new ZoomListener() {
      @Override
      public void zoomApplied(ZoomEvent e) {
          double start = mRenderer.getXAxisMin();
          double stop = (double)mRenderer.getXAxisMax();
          double step = (double)(stop - start) / 5;
          mRenderer.clearXTextLabels();
          for (double i = start; i <= stop; i += step) 
              mRenderer.addXTextLabel(i+1, "label"+(int)i);
          mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
        }

      @Override
      public void zoomReset() { }
  }, true, true);

  graphicalView.addPanListener(new PanListener() {
      @Override
      public void panApplied() {
          double start = mRenderer.getXAxisMin();
          double stop = (double)mRenderer.getXAxisMax();
          double step = (double)(stop - start) / 5;
          mRenderer.clearXTextLabels();
          for (double i = start; i <= stop; i += step) 
              mRenderer.addXTextLabel(i+1, "label"+(int)i);
          mRenderer.setXLabels(0);                
      }
  });
  ```

The custom labels that I want to implement are time in minutes. Can this be done using the 
TimeSeries class with a bar chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is quite good, so I can only suggest an improvement for getting to the labels behavior you need: Use `MathHelper.getLabels(start, stop, approxNumLabels)` instead of your `for` loop between `start` and `stop`.

So your `for` loop would become something like this:

```
List<Double> labels = MathHelper.getLabels(start, stop, 10);
for (Double label : labels) {
  mRenderer.addXTextLabel(label, "label " + label);
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of how one would use this? I tried looking at the docs and couldn't really figure it out.